# jssor - View the stage at motion points. Sweep through timeline

Tags: animation, view, jssor, timeline

jssor - I created a motion point on the timeline at 0 seconds and another at 2 seconds. I edit for scale and rotation but I cannot view the stage at that point in time, only 00:00:00. How can I sweep through the time line to see the animation from 0:00:00 to 00:00:02? Right now, all I can see is that I save it and then preview it.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

Please click on timeline bar to see the stage of a layer.
And you can click the 'Play Button' to review the animation.